# SharePoint Field Definition

Tags: list, sharepoint-2007

I inherited a SharePoint 2007 site collection that has a myriad of subwebs.

To simplify things, though, imagine the following hierarchy:

SiteCollection SC
  SiteCollection Site
    SubWeb1
    SubWeb2

SubWebs 1 and 2 were created from the same site template years ago. They each have a List called ProjTasks that contain the same fields as each other, and even have the same InternalName and Guid. These subWebs do not talk to each other, but they can share the same parent information from the SiteCollection.

What's the best way to update the field definitions across all of the subwebs for a given list?

For the kicker, my specific example is modifying a Choice type's list of choices. While you can usually manually edit a choice by setting one on each line, the only options I have for editing this specific field is changing the Column name and the description (I do not see options for changing the data type or choice options. Any thoughts?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to SC > Site Settings > Site Columns.

Is your field listed there? You should be able to edit it and have the choices cascade down to the lists in your sub sites.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. While I found the field, I am faced with a similar screen (see http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?8f1971cd19.jpg ; note it'll take a bit to load). Is it possible that there is a site column that is defined from the same site gallery? I checked the source of each site column and they all have the same source.

Comment: How was this field initially created? Based on the lack of editable fields and the absence of a Delete button, it looks like it was created in a Feature with Sealed set to true. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979575.aspx

If that is the case, you'll probably need to update the Feature and redeploy or create a new Feature with code that will change the field.

Answer (score 0):

for the benefit of everyone who might experience this problem, i found [this solution](http://laneyvb.blogspot.com/2007/09/changing-status-field-in-helpdesk-or.html) and it worked perfectly. :)